# Question about link between Julia set and Mandelbrot Set

Tags: connectedness, complex-dynamics

I'm searching for a rigorous proof that $c$ is in the Mandelbrot set $M$ if and only if its Julia set $J_c$ is connected. I've read this [question and answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5928/why-are-these-two-definitions-of-the-mandelbrot-set-equivalent) , I understand the answer that is given however, first, I don't know how to prove the assertion he mentioned :

*"the preimage of a curve will have one component if and only if $\ 0 \ $ lies in the the interior of the preimage. This is because $\ 0 \ $ is the critical point of the map $P_c$."*

What I know is that the image of a connected set by a continuous function is a connected set.
Furthermore, I would like to understand that if we assume that a Julia set is connected if and only if it contains $0$, how does it prove that $c \in M \Leftrightarrow J_c$ is connected ?

Answer (score 1):

One can show that if $0$ $D \in J_f$, then $J_f$ is connected. In particular, let $U$ be some neighborhood of $\infty$, and note that $\mathbb C \setminus K$ is the "stuff that goes to infinity, or in other words:

$$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} f^{-n}(U)$$
so that the filled julia set is $J_f:=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} f^{-n}(U^c)$.

Note that $U^c$ is a topological disk, $D$.

*question:* when is $f^{-1}(D)$ a single disk (aka connected component)?

*answer:* when $D$ contains $c$ (or equivalently, $f^{-1}(D)$ contains $0$).

Well for $f^{\prime}(z)=2z=0$ when $z$ is zero, and there are two disks if the forward image does not contain $c$ (apply the riemann-hurwitz formula, where $\chi(D)=1$, but $z^2+c$ would be a double cover, so the characteristic of the preimage will be $2$.)

So, the intersection is connected if and only if the filled julia set contains zero. So, the values of $c \in \mathbb C$ where $0$ is bounded under $z^2+c$ are precisely the ones with connected julia sets.

**note: the image of a connected set is connected, but there is no theorem that says that the forward image of a disconnected set is not connected.

Comment: I dont understand why the complementary is the union of $f^{-n}(U)$ can you explain ? Yes it is the stuff that goes to infinity but why would it be $f^{-n}$ of somthing ?

Comment: Well, there are various definitions for julia sets that agree for the case of quadratic polynomials. If we agree that the julia set is the collection of values that remain bounded after iterating through $f$, then $f^{-1}(U)$ consists of elements in $\mathbb C$ that are mapped to some neighborhood of infinity by $f$, and $\bigcup f^{-n} U$ are the collection of elements that eventually end up in some neighborhood of infinity, so in the limit, they go off to infinity.

Comment: The complement of these elements is the filled julia set, the elements that remain bounded. And taking complements, one can check (by DeMorgan's laws, I think they're called) that $(\bigcup U_n)^c=\bigcap U_n^c$.